# Why using char a="2"; printf("%d",a); gives output 0. Which is Null. But how?

Tags: c

Why using `char a="2"; printf("%d",a);` gives output 0. Which is Null. But how ??

because

```
char a="2";
 printf("%s",a);
```

OUTPUT (null)

Comment: I know it is null...
but why ??
explaination ?

Comment: `="2"` is set address (and overflow as char), not character.

Comment: Shouldn't `char a="2"; printf("%d",a);` be giving `84` as output?

Comment: `printf` probably tries to interpret the value of `a` as an address, then tries to print the string at that address. The whole thing you wrote is undefined behavior. Turn warnings on.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The value of a is **not** 'a', but rather a sliced down remnant of an arbitrary pointer.

Comment: Turn on the warnings of your compiler and **mind those warnings**.

Comment: If i use 
char a =’3′;
printf(“%c”,a);
OUTPUT: 3
But
char a =’432′;
printf(“%c”,a);

OUTPUT: 2.
Coz Char can hold on one character.
So according to char algorithm it will point to last character irrespective of it’s length
for eg 56789
OUTPUT 9
So
when char a=”2″;
It's a string,and we know that string is group of array FOLLOWED BY NULL
here,
char a=’2\0′
Since character can only one character,and which is last by its defination will point to \0.

OUTPUT
printf(“%d”,a); is 0 [ASCII Value of 0]
printf(“%s”,a); is (null) 
printf(“%c”,a); is empty screen.

Answer (score 2):

It is undefined behaviours because `℅s`  expects a `char*`. So you couldn't just print a single character unless it was unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

```
char a= '2';
 printf("%c",a);
```

A single char is given using the ' ' rather than " ", and also when printing use %c instead of %s, because it is single char rather than string of chars.

Answer (score -1):

If we use `char a= "2"; Printf("%d",a);` As `a` is defined as character and,
We are using integer specifier or we say decimal specifier which print the decimal value which is (0)so when you have put the different data type in a variable it will return NULL.
Thats the reason that the instruction is printing the Null(0)

Comment: Please rethink your answer, in particular _say decimal specifier which print the decimal value which is (0)_ because I don't know why that would be null.